# Git clone works with https but not SSH when using Proxy

Tags: git, proxy

In my area, download speed is too slow when git clone. So I use Shadowsocks as my proxy on Macbook Mojave, but shadowsocks can't supply proxy for terminal directly, therefore I use Proxifier as transition. The terminal is iTerm2. They are all the background.

When using proxy, the git clone with ssh can't work and the error is

```
git clone git@github.com:zergtant/pytorch-handbook.git  
Cloning into 'pytorch-handbook'...
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But git clone work well with https when using proxy.

Could anyone give me some hint about this problem?

Thank you very much for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to:

- [configure shadowsocks for SSH traffic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416010/ssh-through-shadowsocks)
- set your Git proxy accodingly

That is:

```
git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'
git config --global https.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'
```

(replace 1080 by your proxyfier port in your case)

---

The [OP georw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7963011/georw) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384945/git-clone-works-with-https-but-not-ssh-when-using-proxy/59385804#comment104968954_59385804) it does work with Shadowsocks alone, but not in combination with Proxifier.

> Proxifier is configured well to proxy socks.
>
> When the error occurs, logs of Proxifier is
>
> ```
> ssh-github. 
>  Com:22 open through proxy127.0.0.1:10801 SOCKS5 
> ssh-github. 
>  Com:22 close21 bytes sent0 bytes received lifetime <1 sec.
> ```
>
> So I found the reason is caused by `ssh` command.
>   When I input `ssh -vvv git@github.com` in the terminal, the output error is
>
> ```
> ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host.
> ```

Comment: Thank you for help, it really works when I don't use Proxifier. But I also want to make clear why git clone doesn't work with ssh when using Proxifier, I think there may be something interesting to be solved.

Comment: @georw Is your Proxifier configured to proxy socks?

Comment: Yes, Proxifier is configured well to proxy socks. When the error occurs, logs of Proxifier is `ssh-github. Com:22 open through proxy127.0.0.1:10801 SOCKS5 ssh-github. Com:22 close21 bytes sent0 bytes received lifetime <1 sec`. So I found the reason is caused by ssh command. When I input `ssh -vvv  git@github.com` in the terminal, the output error is `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`. Then I looked for solutions to this problem but I failed until now.

Comment: @georw OK. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.